# Iterating objects within javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to get objects from an array. For example;

```
var array = [{foo:'bar', baz: 'quz'}];
```

I can access the objects as follows

```
array[0].foo
// Which would return 'bar'
```

But I want to be able to loop through and print all the objects. Is there anyway to do so? Is there anything similar to a wildcard like '*' to grab everything?

Answer (score 5):

Just loop your array:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
  for ( var key in array[i] ) {
    var value = array[i][key];
  }
}
```